# Failed to use gmapping launchfile [new user]

Tags: slam, navigation, roslaunch, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have slam_gmapping package that contains these folders:

```
    slam_gmapping-hydro-devel

       gmapping

           launch

           src

           test

       slam_gmapping
```

I want to launch it with launch file with my own parameters.

the steps I have done are as follow:

- download the package
- copy the package to the catkin_ws --> src
- make a build folder in gmapping folder, so it is now look like this:

  ```
    slam_gmapping-hydro-devel

       gmapping

           launch

           src

           test

           build

       slam_gmapping
  ```
- build the package using make, cmake .., catkin_make (don't know exactly what they do!)

The question is after those steps, "roslaunch gmapping [Tab]" does not find any launch file
But there is a launch file "slam_gmapping_pr2.launch" in launch folder
I also tried to use launch file provided [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/37259/failed-to-access-gmapping-parameter/) . But the same problem exist. The problem is that ROS does not detect any launch file in the gmapping package!
how can I solve the problem?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191479/failed-to-use-gmapping-launchfile-%5Bnew-user%5D/) by [AliAs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20060/alias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[overlay](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) the gmapping package you are building from source.

Without overylaying your package just goto launch folder and do roslaunch from there, but it will call gmapping installed with your ros installation not the package you build from source.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2